# phpMyAdmin SELECT FROM Primary Key Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, primary-key

I am trying to create a table that I can edit within phpMyAdmin. I keep getting a constant error saying "SELECT * FROM "Test2" WHERE ;"

[image]

After doing some searching I found out that it was looking for a primary key, however I already have a primary key.

[image]

I have watched youtube tutorials and I have this set up the same way they do. I cannot figure out why I am getting this error.

Thanks for you time,

Comment: By "constant error" do you mean any time you try to do any activity in phpMyAdmin that error message appears? Or what action triggers the error?

Comment: Any time I do an inline edit, even if there is a primary key. I will update my question to reflect that.

Comment: I will edit as soon as I can, I keep getting an error when trying to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use without `WHERE`:

```
SELECT * FROM `Test2`;
```

or add valid condtion:

```
SELECT * FROM `Test2` WHERE <column_name> = <value>;
-- like
SELECT * FROM `Test2` WHERE id = 1;
```

**[`SQL Synax`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)**:

> *SELECT  ...*
>
> *[FROM table_references]*
>
> *[WHERE where_condition]*

and:

> The WHERE clause, if given, indicates the condition or conditions that
>   rows must satisfy to be selected. **where_condition is an expression
>   that evaluates to true for each row to be selected. The statement
>   selects all rows if there is no WHERE clause.**

Comment: Thanks for your response, I understand the SQL syntax with what I am supposed to write. My question is more about why the inline edit isn't working with phpMyAdmin. If I'm not mistaken the inline edit should auto fill the SQL code, correct?

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, it looks like you haven't typed a WHERE clause in your sql. If this is true, and it's the IDE that feels it really wants a WHERE clause, then add "WHERE 1 = 1" so you satisfy the IDE's requirement but still bring back all rows (because 1 always equals 1 and so nothing will get filtered out):

```
SELECT * FROM `Test2` WHERE 1 = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried adding that into the SQL query. Unfortunately whenever I try to use the inline edit, it still throws the same error. I don't think the inline edit is recognizing the primary key.